# django mocking serializer __init__

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I want in my test to mock the `__init__` of a serializer as follow :

```
serializer = MySerializer(data={'name':'yosi'})
serializer.data # will return {'name':'yosi'} and ignore default behavior, like requiring to call is_valid first
```

I just want the serializer to store data as is, and not do the usual `__init__`

The method I want to test :

MyDAO.py :

```
from ..models import MyModel
from ..serializers import MySerializer

def getAll() -> list[dict]:
    entities = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer = MySerializer(entities, many=True)

    return serializer.data
```

I tried the following, with no success :

```
  def _mocked_seriailzer__init__(self, data, many): 
        self.data = data

    @mock.patch('<PATH_TO_SERIALIZERS_FILE>.MySerializer.__init__', _mocked_seriailzer__init__)
    @mock.patch.object(MyDAO, 'MyModel')
    def test_getall(self, model):
        mockedData = ['mocked-data1', 'mocked-data2', 'mocked-data3']

        model.objects.all.return_value = mockedData

        self.assertEqual(mockedData, MyDAO.getAll())
```

but it complains that the test `is missing 1 required positional argument: 'many'`

```
  def _mocked_seriailzer__init__(self, data, many): 
        self.data = data

    @mock.patch.object(MyDAO, 'MySerializer.__init__', _mocked_seriailzer__init__)
    @mock.patch.object(MyDAO, 'MyModel')
    def test_getall(self, model):
        mockedData = ['mocked-data1', 'mocked-data2', 'mocked-data3']

        model.objects.all.return_value = mockedData

        self.assertEqual(mockedData, MyDAO.getAll())
```

but it says that the MyDAO `does not have the attribute 'CctSerializer.__init__'`

how to mock the `serializer.__init__` correctly?

Comment: You are mocking both of the things, then I'm not getting the purpose of your testcase. Mocking is a crucial part, knowing what exactly to mock is a difficult task in itself.

So can you elaborate a bit what you are trying to test ?

Comment: @SandeepRawat I want to test that the ```getall``` method returns what ```model.objects.all()``` returns, and I don't care about all the ```serializer``` checks. I could also mocke ```serializer.data``` but then it will cut the flow of the method, so I think it won't be a good test. this is a rather simple test, I'm trying to learn how to mock in python in general so I started with the small tests